# Access firebird without using a user and password

Tags: linux, firebird, server

just a simple question...

Is there any possible way to set up firebird so that you don't have to use a user and password
to access the databases on the Server?

I am using Ubuntu Server 14.10 running Firebird superclassic V2.5

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Explain your intentions, please. What is your problem? Maybe there is another solution to your problem.

Comment: Well I have to connect another program called TA+ by Safescan 

(you can download it here as a trial: 
http://www.safescan.com/en-us/productDetail/48/287/time-clocks/safescan-ta-software)

It works just fine if you want to attach a database file on a windows host, but I have to use linux and in this case the program reports that there is no user and password transmitted and that the firebird user has to set up the credentials but in the TA+ program is no form to enter the user and password which are needed for the connection.

Comment: Personally, I don't know any way to bypass Firebird's authentication. But that would feel very odd to me, anyway. Most database systems require authentication. There has to be some configuration file to the program, where credentials (e.g. Firebird default user `SYSADMIN`) can be stored.

Comment: Well I don't know how the program connects to the firebird server on windows if I knew I would just create a user with access to the files on the server so the program could connect but I don't know how to find the login data used by TA+

Comment: Did you have a look at the manual (http://www.safescan.com/media/downloads/Safescan-TA-Software_01_ENG.pdf)? In the appendix, Firebird is mentioned...

Comment: Yes I read it, the syntax is *serverip*:/path/to/your/file.fdb, it works fine on a Windows host but not on a linux host (which I am supposed to use), I always get this error:

http://i.imgur.com/qlt0qPf.png

Comment: FYI, default password is `masterkey`, http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq33/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the credentials used by *TA+* are not defined in Firebird's user database `security2.fdb`.

How is Firebird installed on your Windows and your linux system? Did you use a package provided by *ScanSafe* or is it a vanilla (that is a not modified) Firebird?

Assuming that *TA+* uses default Firebird credentials (user `SYSDBA` password `masterkey`) there is something to consider on linux installations:

- In fact, on Linux a **random password is generated** for user `SYSDBA` when installing Firebird on linux.
- You can view this password in file `SYSDBA.password`.
- You can change the password of user `SYSDBA` (to `masterkey`) by running the scriptfile `bin/changeDBAPassword.sh`.

Try to set `SYSDBA` password to `masterkey` as described.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will apply the changes and try if it works

Comment: I installed firebird via apt-get install firebird2.5-superclassic, and there's another problem the /opt directory is empty.

Comment: Using gsec the server reports this error:

*An error occurred while attempting to modify the user record.
invalid request BLR at offset 118
column USER_NAME is not defined in table USERS*

Comment: I managed to change the password, now the system is running fine and the connection is possible, you are great sir! 
Many many Thanks. :)

Comment: That's great! Maybe, you can explain yet how you resolved the error in gsec. It could be interesting for readers of this Q&A.

Answer (score 1):

I simply ran this command:

`sudo gsec`

`GSEC> modify SYSDBA -pw masterkey`

the SQL changes automatically *masterkey* to *masterke*.

Then I connected TA+ with the syntax mentioned before:

`serverip:/path/to/you/file.fdb`

The program connects using the default credentials.
Database gets found and everything runs like it should be.

The error I got was caused because I forgot to use `modify`.

The connection was not possible because Linux uses a random password for firebird databases, Windows uses the standard password.

Comment: How about using a remote Windows database?